# Accessing Windows Application on Web

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have windows application which consists of many forms.

Now I came across the situation where I want to make this application available online.
How to achieve such a result?

Comment: For the same reason, Web applications are there.

Comment: please have a [Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/412774/647884). Nice suggestion by Jon Skeet to a question like yours.

Comment: Re-design it, and from the design if its possible to work on web the next step is to re-writing. You can only keep the same the algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that does not seem to be possible reason is that both domains are different and for different purposes. Browsers are developed to display HTML and not render windows forms. Secondly HTML will work in all OS even non windows.

Also even if you succeed in doing it it will work only on server and there is no way you can show windows form to the user via browser.

you might want to look into converting it to Silverlight 2.0 instead.